# Button image does not change

Tags: javascript, html, css

Noob here: My button has a text and an image and I want to change both onclick. Text changes but for image i get..crt of null (Looks like it cannot find the image files- both of them are with  the HTML code)Initial image is there but when I click it disappears.

```
<button id= "myButton" type="button" onclick= "change_PL();"><img src="flag_bulgaria.png" id="myImage" style="width:50px; height;50px;">Български</button>


function change_PL() {
    var language = document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML;

    if (language=="Български") {
        language = "English";
        document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML = language; 
        document.getElementById("myImage").src = "flag_american.PNG";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML ="Български";
        document.getElementById("myImage").src = "flag_bulgaria.PNG";
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you swap the initial image to flag_american.png - is it still there at the beginning? If not then you have a typo in your filename.

Answer (score 0):

By default the files need to be in the same folder as the html file. So if those flag images  are in /img or something you need your src to correspond to that. You can try opening up the inspector and checking what file path it's trying to open.

Answer (score 0):

I think the image is present inside button tag and replacing the innerHTML of button completely removes the image tag itself. Try with below code:

```
    <button id= "myButton" type="button" onclick= "change_PL();"><img src="flag_bulgaria.png" id="myImage" style="width:50px; height;50px;">Български</button>

    <script>
    function change_PL() {
        var language = document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML;
        if (language.indexOf("Български") != -1) {
            language = "English";
           document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML = "";
            var img=document.createElement("img");
            img.src="flag_american.PNG";
            img.id="myImage";
            img.style["width"]="50px";
            img.style["height"]="50px";
           document.getElementById("myButton").appendChild(img);
           document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML + language;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML = "";
            var img=document.createElement("img");
            img.src="flag_bulgaria.PNG";
            img.id="myImage";
            img.style["width"]="50px";
            img.style["height"]="50px";
            document.getElementById("myButton").appendChild(img);
            document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML + "Български";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrote wrong `css` code in `img` tag. Replace with this:

```
<img src="flag_bulgaria.png" id="myImage" style="width:50px; height:50px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are written img into button's innerHTML .So after you replace with `.innerHTML` img tag will remove ,so `undefined src` will got .Need to add some element like below..

```
<button type="button" onclick= "change_PL();">
<img src="flag_bulgaria.png" id="myImage" style="width:50px; height;50px;">
<span id= "myButton">Български</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**button.innerHTML** includes **img** tag though. Clone the img for replacement, then remove it. After that, get the actual **language** in **button**. Finally, replace the innerHTML of **button**. See as below.

```js
function change_PL() {
    var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
    var imageBlock = document.getElementById("myImage").cloneNode(true);
    button.removeChild(document.getElementById("myImage"));
    var language = button.innerHTML;
    if (language=="Български") {
        language = "English";
        imageBlock.src = "flag_american.PNG";
        document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML = imageBlock.outerHTML + language; 
    }
    else {
        imageBlock.src = "flag_bulgaria.PNG";
        document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML = imageBlock.outerHTML + "Български"; 
    }
}
```

```html
<button id= "myButton" type="button" onclick= "change_PL();"><img src="flag_bulgaria.png" id="myImage" style="width:50px; height;50px;">Български</button>
```